# Edge coloring question

Tags: graph-theory

I need your help / advice for the next question:

Let $G = (V;E)$ be a 4-regular plane graph with $E = X \cup Y$ (disjoint union). 
For the following conditioning:

> For each vertex  , its four edges alternate between $X$ and $Y$ as we cyclically go around it.

I want to show that it's impossible, and for at least one vertex we can't do it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ can be coloured in the fashion you describe. Then pick any face of the drawing. It must have an even number of sides, since as one cycles round it the edges must alternate between X and Y.

So to show that no such colouring can exist, it suffices show that any 4-valent planar graph must have a face that is a triangle. We do this now.

Suppose $G$ has $v$ vertices and $e$ edges. The fact that $G$ is 4-regular implies that $e=2v$. Suppose that $G$ is drawn so that it has $f$ faces and let $f_n$ faces bounded by an n-gon (for ${n\geq3}$). So $f=\sum_{n\geq3} f_n$ and $2e=\sum_n nf_n$.

Now by Euler's formula:
$$v-e+f=2$$

thus

$$2=e/2-e+f=f-e/2=\sum_{n\geq3} f_n-nf_n/4=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq3} (4-n)f_n$$

The only way for the right hand side to be greater than 0, is if $f_3>0$. I.e the graph contains a triangle.

Comment: I think it would be enough to use ["If $v ≥ 3$ and there are no cycles of length 3, then $e ≤ 2v − 4$."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Other_planarity_criteria). Anyway, nice post!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that result. It certainly makes most of my answer unnecessary.